# How can I simulate an event in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I have the following `OpenLayers 3` code for this:

```
map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
    // Do Something.
});
```

The idea is catch the event principally. I've tried to find something but without success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Decouple the event handler so that it can be triggered by another event.
2. Impersonate the `ol.MapBrowserEvent` members that your event handler requires

The following code should give you an idea on how to do what you need.

```
var doSomething = function(evt) {
    console.log('I've done it');
    // do something with evt.coordinate, evt.pixel or evt.map
};

_map.on('dblclick', doSomething);

$('#simulator').on('click', function() {
    doSomething({
        coordinate: [0,0],
        map: _map,
        pixel: [100,10],
        wasVirtual: true
    });
});
```

You may also want to add a member to the event arguments that signifies the source was virtual, or truly from the map `dblclick` event.